# IE8 displays white page when adding Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

I recently created a website and added some jQuery into it. However doing this makes IE8 display a white page. Whenever I remove the Javascript IE8 renders the site fine. I have tested locally as well as on the internet, the problem still persists.

This is my code to include my .js files:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery/jQuery.js" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery/effects.js" />
```

Comment: You mention that you remove the Javascript and it works fine. Can you post some (or all) of that Javascript?

Answer (score 9):

Try closing the script tags the HTML way:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery/jQuery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery/effects.js"></script>
```

The reason for this is probably that IE can't parse XHTML, instead it tries to convert XHTML to regular HTML and chokes on script tags that uses ending-slash for closing.

Answer (score 1):

Self-closing `script` tags are not interpreted in HTML by any version of Internet Explorer.
It seems to be a very strict interpretation of rules.

You will need to close the `<script>` tags explicitly.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery/jQuery.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery/effects.js"></script>
```

See this question

Comment: It's a perfect interpretation of rules. The rules need a closing tag and there's no such thing as a self-closing (only an auto-closing) tag in HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Self-closing tags are part of XHTML, not HTML. No versions of IE before IE9 support XHTML so I'll assume that you're serving HTML. Close script tags in HTML with `</script>`.